# CSS Sprite Images are extremely slow to load

Tags: jquery, css, loading, css-sprites

I am testing my website and my main logo and social media icons that are CSS sprite images are very slow to load and wait for the entire web page to load before displaying. Any help would be great!

Primarily an issue using firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has *nothing* to do with your logo and sprites.

Have you seen your total page footprint? **You are currently making 109 requests, totalling 4.24MB!**

**The cause:**

This is mainly being caused by the fact that you seem to load your entire portfolio on one page and show each section with JavaScript. Instead, try to seperate the content and more than one page or use AJAX to load content on-the-fly.

Use tools like Firebug of Google Chrome's builtin developer tools to profile your website. It will help you gain more insights as to what it is you are doing and what you *should* do.

[image: screenshot of google profiler]

Comment: Thank @Aron Rotteveel How would I go about implementing AJAX into this project? It also appears to only be a real problem in Firefox.

Comment: @user720033 that is a topic that is too broad to be answered in a single answer or comment. Search this website and google for AJAX tutorials and I suggest using a JS framework like **jQuery** to make your life easier :)

Answer (score 0):

check also:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/
Used the firebug plugin before and it's very useful. And the **Web Performance Best Practices and Rules** are a must read.